# Golang Gphoto2 slow response

Tags: rest, go, cgo

I'm having a somewhat strange issue with a Go program I wrote that I think may be related to the C library that I'm calling.  The longer the program runs the longer the response time becomes for retrieving a picture.  I'm not what would even be considered a passable C programmer and I'm still new to load C from Go.  I wrote a simple REST interface around a gphoto2 library that allow me to remotely trigger a camera and retrieve the photo.  Ideally I'm going to use it to create a timelapse so I need it to run very long term.  Here's the wrapper:

```
camera := new(gphoto2go.Camera)
err := camera.Init()
if err > 0 {
    log.Println(err)
}
r := gin.Default()
r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "pong",
    })
})

r.GET("/shot", func(c *gin.Context) {
    //camera.Interrupt()
    cameraFilePath, err := camera.TriggerCaptureToFile()
    if err == 0 {

        cameraFileReader := camera.FileReader(cameraFilePath.Folder, cameraFilePath.Name)
        defer cameraFileReader.Close()
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        buf.ReadFrom(cameraFileReader)

        //camera.DeleteFile(cameraFilePath.Folder, cameraFilePath.Name)
        encodedImage := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf.Bytes())
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "image": encodedImage,
        })
        buf.Reset()
        //c.Data(200, "image/jpeg", buf.Bytes())

    } else {
        log.Println(gphoto2go.CameraResultToString(err))
        c.Error(errors.New(gphoto2go.CameraResultToString(err)))
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gphoto2go.CameraResultToString(err))
        return
    }

})
r.Run()
```

Here's the C function from libgphoto2-dev that it's calling:

```
func (c *Camera) TriggerCaptureToFile() (CameraFilePath, int) {
var path CameraFilePath
var _path C.CameraFilePath
err := C.gp_camera_capture(c.camera, CAPTURE_IMAGE, &_path, c.context)
path.Name = C.GoString(&_path.name[0])
path.Folder = C.GoString(&_path.folder[0])
log.Println(path.Name)
log.Println(path.Folder)
return path, int(err)
```

}

Finally, here's the output.  When I first start the program it takes just a few seconds to retrieve the picture, after a couple of hours it's north of 2 mintues.

```
Response Status: 200 OK
2017/05/28 15:50:35 
Response Time: 3.217692348s
2017/05/28 15:50:35 


Response Status: 200 OK
2017/05/28 19:27:04 
Response Time: 2m5.010491487s
2017/05/28 19:27:04
```

Comment: What is the type of the camera? In what platform do you run the go application? According to [the manual](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/api/gphoto2-camera_8h.html#a8fa6903e3bf0ab26edc4e915512aa44f), the resulting file of `gp_camera_capture` will be stored in the camera. Maybe it will affect the performance. To assist debugging, measure [execution time of a function call](https://play.golang.org/p/yj1-F8KxX7) in the server so you know exactly which function takes long execution time.

Comment: It's a Nikon D90 and I'm running it on a Raspberrypi2.  What's interesting is that the call to gp_camera_capture does not place the file on the camera for the D90.  At least not on the SDcard, it puts the file somewhere but I don't really understand where it goes.  Just /capture001.jpg by what the debug is telling me.  Looking on the camera that file does not exist.  I think it might be a resource issue with the camera itself now, I wrote a function that releases the camera back to the OS and inits it every request and that seems better.  There's just a problem with occasional failure now.

Comment: Make sure you lock the `/shot` handler (e.g. using `sync.Mutex`) until you finish using the camera to capture one image, since in a web application, handler (`/shot`) may be called by different client concurrently.

Comment: Good thinking, I added that too.  I'd still like to understand why the requests get progressively slower.  I think it's related to the issue where `gp_camera_capture` is not actually saving the image to the camera and instead is saving it to some other location.